# Develop an Intelligent Code Completion in Java

Tags: java

I want to know if there is a way to write my own code completion in a java swing environment. I have a program and would like to provide hints for the user while he is typing. I am already giving them some hints through a popup menu. But, the problem is that it is in the way. It is a menu, so it does not feel as optional as eclipse's code completion. Do you know of a better way than a popup menu?

Thanks,

Comment: eclipse is open source. Check it out [http://wiki.eclipse.org/CVS_Howto](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CVS_Howto).

Comment: NetBeans is OpenSource. Check out the tutorial: http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-completion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a look at [RSyntaxTextArea](http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/). It supports code completion (with CTRL+SPACE), syntax highlighting, line numbering, bracket matching... much of the basic features you expect from a code editor component.